# Issue about forget_bias

Tags: tensorflow

I'm going to write a BasicLSTMCell with C++,and I need check it work well.
I used `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell` to implement a LSTM with 4 cells,and I set
forget_bias to 1.Then I Check the LSTM'bias using this code:

```py
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    with tf.variable_scope("LSTM"):
    Cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(4,forget_bias=1,state_is_tuple=True)
Sessin=tf.Session()
state=Cell.zero_state(1,dtype=tf.float32)
with  tf.variable_scope("Ut_def"):
    out,D=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            cell=Cell,inputs=Feed,
            initial_state=state,
            time_major=False)
Sessin.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#Saver.save(Sessin,"./123/Var",global_step=1)
out,D=Sessin.run([out,D],feed_dict={Feed:np.arange(8).reshape(1,2,4)})
tf.train.Saver().save(Sessin,"./123/Var",global_step=1)
trainable_vars_dict = {}
for key in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES):
    trainable_vars_dict[key.name] = Sessin.run(key)
    # Checking the names of the keys
    print(key.name)
lstm_weight_vals = trainable_vars_dict["Ut_def/RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix:0"]
B=trainable_vars_dict["Ut_def/RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Bias:0"]
print(B)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

But I found these bias were all zeros whatever I changed the `forget_bias`.

Someone know that what it is going on?

For figuring out how lstm work,I just using   wights and bias extracting from tensorflow for getting same result. Absolutely they are not equivalent.

```py
w_i, w_C, w_f, w_o = np.split(lstm_weight_vals, 4, axis=1)
w_xi = w_i[:4, :]
w_hi = w_i[4:, :]
w_xC = w_C[:4, :]
w_hC = w_C[4:, :]
w_xf = w_f[:4, :]
w_hf = w_f[4:, :]
w_xo = w_o[4:, :]
w_ho = w_o[4:, :]
Input=tf.range(4,dtype=tf.float32)
Input=tf.reshape(Input,shape=[1,4])
i=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(tf.zeros(shape=[1,4]),w_xi)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hi))
o=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(tf.zeros(shape=[1,4]),w_xo)+tf.matmul(Input,w_ho))
g=tf.tanh(tf.matmul(tf.zeros(shape=[1,4]),w_xC)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hC))
f=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(tf.zeros(shape=[1,4]),w_xf)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hf))
Cstate=tf.zeros(shape=[1,4])*f+i*g
Hstate=tf.tanh(Cstate)*o
Input=Input+4
i=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Cstate,w_xi)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hi))
o=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Cstate,w_xo)+tf.matmul(Input,w_ho))
g=tf.tanh(tf.matmul(Cstate,w_xC)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hC))
f=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Cstate,w_xf)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hf))
Cstate=Cstate*f+i*g

Hstate=tf.tanh(Cstate)*o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has found  wrong code. Code should like this:

```py
i=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Hstate,w_xi)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hi))
o=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Hstate,w_xo)+tf.matmul(Input,w_ho))
g=tf.tanh(tf.matmul(Hstate,w_xC)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hC))
f=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Hstate,w_xf)+tf.matmul(Input,w_hf)+1)
```

It's `Hstate` instead of `Csatae`.